# Find the distinct ways for this binary operation

Tags: combinatorics, associativity

Let ∗ be a non-associative binary operation defined on a set . For 1, 2, … ,  ∈ , how can I find the number of distinct ways of performing the operation 1 ∗ 2 ∗ ⋯ ∗  ?

I tried to enumerate it as `1 ∗ (2 ∗ ⋯ ∗ n)`, `1 ∗ 2 ∗ (x3 * ⋯ ∗ n)` but could not really come up with a solution.

Comment: Presumably you are asking how many ways this expression can be parenthesized.  The fact that ∗ is non-associative does not imply that all such parenthesizations will produce different results (but associativity would imply all parenthesizations produce the same result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n$ be the number you want.

We get:

$S_{n+1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} S_kS_{n-k}$. and $S_2=1$.

You can identify this as the catalan recurrence, so the answer is $\binom{2n-2}{n-1}/n$.